# BlackBerry ListField Height Not Changing

Tags: blackberry, listfield

In the ListField,If i click on selected index or focus on the selected index,i want to chane the height of the selected field automatically....

Can u help how to implement that ....

Advance thanks..

Answer (score 1):

A `ListField` can only have uniform row sizes, so unfortunately it won't be something as simple as changing the height of the selected row. If you're wanting it to be able to change sizes, you'll probably need to write your own. It wouldn't be too terribly difficult by just adding fields to a `VerticalFieldManager`and making that scrollable, though you will need to handle selection painting, row indexing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A ListField can only have uniform row sizes... but if you use horizontalFieldManager for the list row. you can change the size on TouchEvent by setting height of the horizontalFieldManager